# Create SwiftUI view with an image with multiple clickable areas

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to create a view which scales a ZStack of images. When i give them an `onTapGesture` only the top layer is available even on its transparent areas when the background should be tapable.

I did try to alter the renderingMode to template to mark the transparent areas as not rendered.
I even tried to create UIButton as replacement because in older version UIKit transparent areas were not clickable.

```
ZStack{
    Image("backgound"))
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
    Image("foreground")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
    Image("clickableHighlight1")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .onTapGesture {
            //do stuff specific to highlite1 area
        }
    Image("clickableHighlight2")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .onTapGesture {
            //do stuff specific to highlite2 area
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how relevant it is, but I came up with a solution that maybe someone else will benefit from.

I did convert my clickable areas to SwiftUI shapes using a converter (https://svg-to-swiftui.quassum.com/) this can be difficult depending on the svg you are trying to convert. For me it worked fine because the svg contains simple paths.
I gave the resulting shapes semantic names and pasted them above my views. Sadly one is not able to use scaled to fit modifier to scale the shapes because the `onTapGesture` recognizes the hole area and not just the highlighted area. So I ended up using an `overlay`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Image("background")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .overlay{
                ZStack{
                  Circle() //use the Shape you get from the converter
                      .onTapGesture {
                          print("Circle is pressed")
                      }
                  Rectangle() //use the Shape you get from the converter
                      .onTapGesture {
                          print("Rectangle is pressed")
                      }
                }
            }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()

            ClickableArea(imageName: "clickableHighlight1") {
                // Do stuff specific to highlight 1 area
                print("Clicked on Highlight 1")
            }

            ClickableArea(imageName: "clickableHighlight2") {
                // Do stuff specific to highlight 2 area
                print("Clicked on Highlight 2")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ClickableArea: View {
    let imageName: String
    let action: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        Image(imageName)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .onTapGesture {
                action()
            }
    }
}

@main
struct YourApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

this code helps you make clickable image

Comment: Tanks for your answer. It improves the readability. Unfortunately the actual it doesn't solve the actual Problem. The Problem is, that all of the resources have the same Measurement. The two Clickables  have a small foreground area which is placed at different positions on the background. Imagine the background as an tree and the Clickables as two apples with different meanings.